# Nextjs Mutation in beta version

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I read docs in beta about the mutation, but the data in server side not change when the router reload

Hi, I just test the beta version of NextJs and about mutation feature

This is my server side code

```
export async function getCategories() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/banks?size=1");
    if (res.status === ResponseStatusCode.OK) {
      // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export default async function Products() {
  const categories = await getCategories();

  return (
    <section className="py-20 bg-gray-100">
        <Test id={categories?.id} />
    </section />
)
}
```

This is the `Test` client side code:

```
"use client";

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState, useTransition } from "react";

interface Todo {
  id: number;
}

export const Test = (props: Todo) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<any>(props.id);

  // Create inline loading UI
  const isMutating = isFetching || isPending;

  async function handleChange() {
    setIsFetching(true);
    // Mutate external data source
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/users?size=1`,
      {
        method: "GET",
      }
    );

    setIsFetching(false);
    const data = await response.json();
    setTodo(data.id);
    // setTodo(response.json().then((data) => data?.id))

    startTransition(() => {
      //   // Refresh the current route and fetch new data from the server without
      //   // losing client-side browser or React state.
      router.refresh();
    });
  }

  return <button onClick={handleChange}>{todo}</button>;
};
```

But when I click the the button, just the id of `todo` change and it not refresh the data in the server side. The id of server side not change or I understood wrong something

Comment: In `handleChange`, you are making just a GET request; you do not seem to have any mutating system on the API part. What are you expecting to be changed on the server?

Comment: i have the line `router.refresh()` to make it revalidate again. But the data not change